# Javascript callback functions returning empty object

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I can't seem to get this callback function right.

```
dispatch: function (query, callback) {
  var result = new Object() ;
  var qd = new queryDispatcher.init();
  var google = qd.callGoogle(query, function(a,b) {
    result.gdocs = a ; 
    result.gtotal = b ; 
  }) ;       

  var bing = qd.callBing(query, function(a,b) {
    result.bdocs = a ; 
    result.btotal = b ;            
  }) ; 

  var yahoo = qd.callYahoo(query, function(c,d) {
    result.ydocs = c ; 
    result.ytotal = d ; 
  }) ; 

  callback(result);
},
```

As you can see, the query is dispatched and the results are being appended to the results object. However, the callback(result) is still returning an empty object to the parent function which is as follows.

```
var results = meta.dispatch(query, 
  function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are there really that many newlines in your code when writing/editing it? I do wonder, as an honest question, because I don't understand how code ends up so badly formatted on here in such a variety of ways.

Comment: You've included the "asynchronous" tag on your question, and that's your answer...

Comment: @GrantThomas: I agree, how on earth do you end up with such indentation? Doesn't seem like a bad copy/paste.

Comment: @nnnnnn Can you elaborate a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callback is synchronous, but the properties are asynchronously fetched. When you callback is called, all you got is indeed an empty object.

You should only call the callback after you have all the three answer (use a counter, for example).

```js
dispatch: function(query, callback) {
  var result = new Object(),
      qd = new queryDispatcher.init(),
      counter = 3;

  var google = qd.callGoogle(query, function(a,b) {
    result.gdocs = a ; 
    result.gtotal = b ; 
    checkCallback();
  }) ;       

  var bing = qd.callBing(query, function(a,b) {
    result.bdocs = a ; 
    result.btotal = b ;   
    checkCallback();         
  }) ; 

  var yahoo = qd.callYahoo(query, function(c,d) {
    result.ydocs = c ; 
    result.ytotal = d ; 
    checkCallback();
  });

  function checkCallback() {
    if (--counter == 0) {
      callback(result);
    }
  }
}
```

But I'd rather go with [promises](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/11/asynchronous-programming-in-javascript-with-promises.aspx) instead of callbacks. It's a powerful approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember that with an asynchronous approach, the flow of execution is not the same as the flow of your code. After you have set up the asynchronous functions, the execution flow will continue, but the results from your async functions might not be ready yet. In this case, when execution reaches `callback(result)`, nothing has been set on the `result` object yet since none of the async functions have finished. So you need to chain your async functions in some way. A "brute force" (non parallel) approach would be something like:

```
qd.callGoogle(query, function(result1) {
    qd.callBing(query, function(result2) {
        qd.callYahoo(query, function(result3) {
             callback(combinedResult);
        });
    })
})
```

But I really recommend that you look into a flow library, like for instance [node-seq](https://github.com/substack/node-seq) if you're using nodejs, or [jQuery Deferred/Promise](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) for in browser use.